# MS Excel direction change of drag down reference

Tags: excel

Suppose, in Cell **A1** of *Sheet2* I use this formula.

```
=AVERAGE(Sheet1!A1:A10)
```

Now when I drag down from **A1** to **A3**

```
A2 will be =AVERAGE(Sheet1!A2:A11)
A3 will be =AVERAGE(Sheet1!A3:A12)
```

However I want it in a transpose way. Such as,

```
A2 will be =AVERAGE(Sheet1!B1:B10)
A3 will be =AVERAGE(Sheet1!C1:C10)
```

Means, I will use drag down rather than dragging to side, yet I'll get the answer in transpose way, more specifically, I want to change column index rather than changing row index by dragging a formula down.
Is there any way to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use this formula in Sheet2 A1 and copy down

```
=AVERAGE(OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,,ROW()-1,10))
```

As you drag it down, `ROW()-1` increases by 1 and this is the column offset from A1.

In A1, `ROW()-1` returns 0 so there is no offset, but as you go down this increases by 1 and this is the column offset from A1 - so in row 2 this becomes B1 etc.

The 10 indicates the size of the relevant range to be averaged.

Answer (score 2):

In **A1** enter:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$Z$10,1,ROW()):INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$Z$10,10,ROW()))
```

and copy downward.

If you need more than 26 items, increase the ***Z*** in the formula.

Comment: How is that exactly helping me to find average? Sorry but, after using the formula it is only giving me the value of A1 of sheet one. Not the average of A1:A10. Could you please elaborately answer?

Comment: @Pratyya10  Sorry.............. **my error** ...........see revised formula.